# Storing data temporarily in an ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using a singleton dictionary collection to store a collection of users so that the users can access the api using their guid to access their credit card details.

Is there a more secure way to store data rather than using a singleton dictionary collection? It's only for temporary storage - no database involved.

Comment: TBH, I don't think this style would be PCI compliant. Are you? But, Moving on, you could use temp json files with this "user data" and then access them through a service if you really want to go that route or hell, even apply authorization rules on top of that json "configuration" ... but please don't :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would probably question a single guid being the keys to the kingdom in terms of credit card details... Infact I would also question giving out full credit card details under any circumstances from an API.

But let's pretend the question is more about temporary storage in general.

In memory storage is fine, but you will run into two problems.

1. When your app is restarted, the cache is "lost".
2. You will be unable to scale horizontally as the cache is for a single app. Other machines within your server pool will have to build their own cache (And you will have other things like sticky sessions to worry about etc).

A better option is indeed Redis. You will need to download redis [from here](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis) assuming you are on windows and install it. Obviously when deployed you can use something like Azure Redis etc. And for the code,  luckily Microsoft have done most of the work for you. Taken mostly from this post : http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/01/06/using-redis-cache-net-core/

Install this package in your .net core app.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis
```

In your configure services method in your startup.cs, you need to add Redis as a cache service. You do it like so :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddDistributedRedisCache(option =>
    {
        option.Configuration = "127.0.0.1";
        option.InstanceName = "master";
    });
}
```

Then you can just ask for the IDistributedCache in your controllers/services. Something like the following :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

    public HomeController(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
    {
        _distributedCache = distributedCache;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        //You can access _distributedCache here. 
    }
}
```

Comment: that dotnetcoretutorials.com link has so many ads my browser is on the brink of crashing.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when application restarts? Don't you lose data after that? If don't (your list is hardcoded) i think it's nothing wrong with collection. But after each app restart you lose your data and need to reenter again, you can try like https://redis.io/ for caching user collection. After application restart you won't lose your collection data.